# Android Navigation Components Error: 'bad operand types for binary operator' in generated file

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, kotlin-android-extensions, android-navigation-graph

I am working on an app that incorporates Android Navigation Components. A generated build file `MyFragmentDirections.java`is preventing the app from being built, this file contains numerous errors similar to the ones below:

```
error: bad operand types for binary operator '=='
      if (mainItemId == null) {
                     ^
  first type:  int
  second type: <null>
...
error: int cannot be dereferenced
      if (getMainItemId() != null ? !getMainItemId().equals(that.getMainItemId()) : that.getMainItemId() != null) {
```

I suspect the problem is in a Navigation Argument I have defined:

```
        <argument
            android:name="mainItemId"
            app:argType="int"/>
```

I have used `int` instead of `Int` because examples I have seen on Android Developer use `string` instead of `String`.

Changing to `Int` results in a different set of errors elsewhere in my code when I reference the navigation argument:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but kotlin.Int was expected

Cannot access class 'Int'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

Can anyone explain why this happening and provide a solution?

The relevant portion of my Gradle build file (Module) is below:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin' // edited see comments 
}
...
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.1'
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'` instead of `id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'` (which is what would actually generate Kotlin code)?

Comment: No reason, but making the change, syncing Gradle, and attempting to rebuild results in an unresolved reference error for `int` or `Int` depending upon which one I use in my navigation argument definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#supported_argument_types), the **only** correct `argType` for an integer is `app:argType="integer"` - that will make a `int` in Java code or a `kotlin.Int` in Kotlin code.